# Why most of the online code examples are using override keyword when conform protocol function?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I am using Swift 5 XCode 12.

I notice if I conform protocol function, the keyword `override` is not required. For instance

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
```

However, I look at quite a number of online example code. For instance, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
```

I notice many of them are using `override` keyword.

If I apply `override` keyword, I will be getting error

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

May I know why it is so? Is it because the online examples are using old XCode, or old Swift?

Comment: You're mixing up protocol conformance (interfaces) and inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the examples are using a subclass of [UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller) they need the `override` keyword, due to the fact that `UITableViewController` has already implemented `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

If your view controller is a subclass of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) instead and implements `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, then the `override` keyword should be removed.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```